# org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: pack1.Persoana

Tags: hibernate, hibernate.cfg.xml, hbmxml, mappingexception

I receive this error and I don't know what is wrong with my hbm.xml file.
I use Eclipse Mars and Hibernate 5.0.2.

Error:

```
Nov 15, 2015 11:49:19 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.2.Final}
Nov 15, 2015 11:49:19 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Nov 15, 2015 11:49:19 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Nov 15, 2015 11:49:19 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.0.Final}
Nov 15, 2015 11:49:20 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Nov 15, 2015 11:49:20 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000401: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test]
Nov 15, 2015 11:49:20 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=root, password=****}
Nov 15, 2015 11:49:20 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000006: Autocommit mode: false
Nov 15, 2015 11:49:20 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
Nov 15, 2015 11:49:20 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: pack1.Persoana
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionFactoryImpl.java:776)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionImpl.java:1451)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:177)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:32)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:678)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:670)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:665)
    at pack1.Main.insert(Main.java:74)
    at pack1.Main.main(Main.java:34)
org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: pack1.Persoana
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionFactoryImpl.java:776)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionImpl.java:1451)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:177)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:32)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:678)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:670)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:665)
    at pack1.Main.insert(Main.java:74)
    at pack1.Main.main(Main.java:35)
org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: pack1.Persoana
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionFactoryImpl.java:776)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionImpl.java:1451)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:177)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:32)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:678)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:670)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:665)
    at pack1.Main.insert(Main.java:74)
    at pack1.Main.main(Main.java:36)
org.hibernate.UnknownEntityTypeException: Unable to locate persister: pack1.Persoana
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.locateEntityPersister(SessionFactoryImpl.java:792)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.locateEntityPersister(SessionImpl.java:2641)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.access$2500(SessionImpl.java:164)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.<init>(SessionImpl.java:2579)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.<init>(SessionImpl.java:2566)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.byId(SessionImpl.java:1044)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:955)
    at pack1.Main.update(Main.java:87)
    at pack1.Main.main(Main.java:42)
org.hibernate.UnknownEntityTypeException: Unable to locate persister: pack1.Persoana
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.locateEntityPersister(SessionFactoryImpl.java:792)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.locateEntityPersister(SessionImpl.java:2641)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.access$2500(SessionImpl.java:164)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.<init>(SessionImpl.java:2579)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.<init>(SessionImpl.java:2566)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.byId(SessionImpl.java:1044)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:955)
    at pack1.Main.delete(Main.java:105)
    at pack1.Main.main(Main.java:43)
Nov 15, 2015 11:49:21 PM org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Persoana is not mapped [from Persoana]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.generateQueryException(QuerySyntaxException.java:79)
    at org.hibernate.QueryException.wrapWithQueryString(QueryException.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:218)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:142)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:150)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:298)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:236)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1825)
    at pack1.Main.afisare(Main.java:53)
    at pack1.Main.main(Main.java:44)
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Persoana is not mapped
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.requireClassPersister(SessionFactoryHelper.java:171)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElementFactory.addFromElement(FromElementFactory.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromClause.addFromElement(FromClause.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.createFromElement(HqlSqlWalker.java:321)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3678)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElementList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3567)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:708)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:564)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:301)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:249)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:262)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:190)
    ... 9 more
```

Main Class:

```
package pack1;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Iterator;
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;

public class Main {

    private static SessionFactory factory;
    private static Configuration configuration;

    private static ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try{

            configuration = new Configuration().addResource("./hibernate.cfg.xml");
            configuration.configure();

            serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
            factory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);

            //Configuration config = new Configuration();
            //factory = config.configure().buildSessionFactory();
            insert(5, "Maria", 20);
            insert(6, "Ioana", 19);
            insert(7, "Denisa", 14);
        }
        catch(Throwable ex){
            System.err.println("Failed to create sessionFactory object." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
        update(2,22);
        delete(3);
        afisare();

    }

    private static void afisare( ){
        Session session = factory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = null;
        try{
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            Query query= session.createQuery("from Persoana");//Hibernate Query Language (HQL)
            //se poate rula SQL cu createSQLQuery(…)
            List<Persoana> persoane = query.list();
            for (Persoana p: persoane){
                System.out.println(p);
            }
            tx.commit();
        }catch (HibernateException e) {
            if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            session.close();
        }
    }

    private static void insert(int id, String nume, int varsta){
        Session session = factory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = null;
        try{
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            Persoana pers= new Persoana(id, nume, varsta);
            session.save(pers);
            tx.commit();
        }catch (HibernateException e) {
            if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally { session.close(); }
    }

    private static void update(Integer id, int varsta ){
        Session session = factory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = null;
        try{
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            Persoana pers= (Persoana)session.get(Persoana.class, id);
            pers.setVarsta( varsta );
            session.update(pers);
            tx.commit();
        }catch (HibernateException e) {
            if (tx!=null)
                tx.rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            session.close();
        }
    }

    private static void delete(Integer id){
        Session session = factory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = null;
        try{
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            Persoana pers= (Persoana)session.get(Persoana.class, id);
            session.delete(pers);
            tx.commit();
        }catch (HibernateException e) {
            if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            session.close();
        }
    }

}
```

This is the other class:

```
package pack1;

public class Persoana {

    private int id;
    private String nume;
    private int varsta;
    public Persoana(){}
    public Persoana(int id,String nume,int varsta){
        this.id=id;
        this.nume=nume;
        this.varsta=varsta;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getNume() {
        return nume;
    }
    public void setNume(String nume) {
        this.nume = nume;
    }
    public int getVarsta() {
        return varsta;
    }
    public void setVarsta(int varsta) {
        this.varsta = varsta;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return id + ", " + nume + ", " + varsta;
    }

}
```

This is my hibernate.cfg.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">rootpass</property>
        <mapping class="Persoana" resource="Persoana.hbm.xml"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

And here is my hbm.xml file

```
<!-- Generated Nov 15, 2015 2:03:44 PM by Hibernate Tools 3.5.0.Final -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="pack1.Persoana" table="PERSOANA">
        <id name="id" type="int">
            <column name="ID" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <property name="nume" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="NUME" />
        </property>
        <property name="varsta" type="int">
            <column name="VARSTA" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: `<mapping class="Persoana" resource="Persoana.hbm.xml"/>` , class attribute seems wrong to me

Comment: I need to say, this question is poorly asked.  You should make up something as minimal as possible which demonstrate the problem, instead of dumping out lots of irrelevant information

Answer (score 2):

Try to put package name into `hibernate-mapping`:

```
<hibernate-mapping package="pack1">
    <class name="Persoana" table="PERSOANA">
```

And remove class definition(`class="Persoana"`) from `mapping` in cfg.xml.

Answer (score 2):

Use `<mapping resource="Persoana.hbm.xml" />` in hibernate.cfg.xml should be suffice

Answer (score 2):

SOLVED!
The problem that I found is related to the version of Hibernate. I had switched to Hibernate 4.3.6 Final and it works fine! So, do not use Hibernate version 5.0.2!